# Jest: `npm test` not displaying "Watch Usage" options in Windows Git Bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, jestjs

I am new to React and attempting to use `npm test`.

From the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/), it is my understanding that every time `npm test` runs, it starts the watcher. The watcher is supposed to display a list of commands titled "Watch Usage". This includes commands such as a, f and q.

When I run `npm test`, watcher appears to work because it runs the tests and reruns them if I save a file.

However, it does not display the "Watch Usage" list and if I type any of the "Watch Usage" commands, nothing happens.

How can I enable the "Watch Usage" commands?

Comment: `npm test` works in cmd.exe. The Jest VSCode extension is also helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I was attempting to run this command in Git Bash. I have not found a solution to make it work in Git Bash.

However, you can instead run the command in cmd.exe and it will work properly.

The Jest VSCode extension can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with running Jest inside Git Bash on Windows. The terminal codes for updating the screen are not correctly handled, and I've been unable to find a reason or fix for this searching Google.

If you run `npm test` from a DOS prompt, then it seems to work fine, but if you run `npm test` from a Git Bash prompt the progress feedback from Jest is missing.

You can enable colors by running `npm run test -- --colors` which gets Jest to output the color status for tests in Git Bash, but strangely the colors are working but the progress is still not shown.

The only successful work around that I've found is running Jest from inside `winpty` if you're using Git Bash.

```
winpty npm.cmd test
```

So what I do is add an alternative npm script to my `package.json` file for running on Git Bash inside Windows.

```
    "wintest": "winpty npm.cmd run test",
```

Then you can just run that instead.

```
npm run wintest
```

It's not a perfect solution, but at least you can see the progress correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate watch mode, modify your package.json:

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch",
}
```

run `npm test`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after some digging I found out that in VSCODE the git bash executable that was used was taken from `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` while the start menu was pointing to `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`.

When I opened the executable from the `bin` folder it worked and showed the `Watch Usage`

Update:
Reinstalling git bash also solved it for me ‍♂️